# Is there an easy way to automate the testing of BusinessObjects reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, migration, business-objects

We will be migrating from BO 3.1 to BO 4.1.

It is proposed to manually schedule, save and compare reports from both environments then manually compare them. Surely all this can be automated?

Specifically, can we automate:

1. The scheduling and exporting of reports to a single network folder.
2. Comparing reports of different formats, i.e. Word, Excel, PDF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create report publications in each system to generate the reports to a folder and if they are generated as PDF's you could then use document comparison software, we use [Compare Docs](http://www.docscorp.com/products/comparedocs/document-comparison-tool/) from Docs Corp for PDF and DOC comparisons.

We went through an upgrade of XIr2 to XI3.1 a few years back, as our finance team where the majority users of the reporting system we had them identify their top reports and focused on them, running the report in the two systems at the same time as we have some reports using a data warehouse and some using SQL and some queries ran even a couple minutes apart would affect the results. We then manually compared the reports.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the [BI Platform SDK](http://scn.sap.com/community/restful-sdk/blog/2012/11/17/using-web-intelligence-rest-web-services-to-log-into-the-bi-platform-server-javascript-and-c) to schedule reports--the link references a REST SDK, but there are COM and SOAP ones too.
2. In 4.0, you can use [WebI's REST SDK](https://scn.sap.com/community/restful-sdk/blog/2012/11/17/using-web-intelligence-rest-web-services-to-retrieve-information-about-reports-javascript-and-c) to export the report's data; In 3.x, you need to use the [COM SDK](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-51447).  There might also be a Java version.